Auth0 integration with Next.js and ASP.NET Core
I'm integrating Auth0 into my Next.js frontend and ASP.NET Core backend application. While the integration for authentication and authorization generally works, I am encountering issues when protecting certain endpoints and validating JWT tokens.
Here is the setup and the issue I'm facing:
Backend Configuration (Program.cs):
var auth0Settings = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Auth0Settings");

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => 
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options => 
{
    options.Authority = $"https://{auth0Settings["Domain"]}";
    options.Audience = auth0Settings["Audience"];
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidIssuer = $"https://{auth0Settings["Domain"]}",
        ValidAudience = auth0Settings["Audience"],
    };

    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Authentication failed: {context.Exception.Message}");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnTokenValidated = context =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Token validated: {context.SecurityToken}");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnChallenge = context =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Authentication challenge: {context.Error} - {context.ErrorDescription}");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});

// Add authorization policies for roles
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
    options.AddPolicy("Developer", policy => policy.RequireRole("Developer"));
    options.AddPolicy("Registered", policy => policy.RequireRole("Registered"));
});

Controller Setup (PostController.cs):
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[HttpPost("create")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePost([FromBody] Post newPost)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var createdPost = await _postManager.CreatePost(newPost);
    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetPost), new { id = createdPost.Id }, createdPost);
}

Frontend Access Token Fetching (/api/getAccessToken/route.ts):
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { getAccessToken, withApiAuthRequired } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

const GET = withApiAuthRequired(async function GET(req) {
    const res = new NextResponse();
    const { accessToken } = await getAccessToken(req, res);
    return NextResponse.json({ accessToken: accessToken }, res);
});

export { GET };

HTTP Request Helper (httpRequest.ts):
import { AxiosHttpRequest } from '../services/api/core/AxiosHttpRequest';

const httpRequest = async (): Promise<AxiosHttpRequest> => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/getAccessToken', {
        method: 'GET',
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch access token');
    }

    const { accessToken } = await response.json();

    return new AxiosHttpRequest({
        BASE: process.env.BASE_URL ?? 'http://localhost:5149',
        VERSION: '1',
        WITH_CREDENTIALS: false,
        CREDENTIALS: 'include',
        HEADERS: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
    });
};

export default httpRequest;

Issues:
JWT Token Decryption Failure: When making requests to protected endpoints, I receive the following error:
Authentication failed: IDX10609: Decryption failed. No Keys tried: token: '[Security Artifact of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.SecurityArtifact' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/SecurityArtifactLogging.]'. 
Invalid Signature: The token returned seems to have an invalid signature, as verified by jwt.io
Questions:

Why is the JWT token signature invalid, and how can this be resolved?
Have I missed any essential part of the authentication and token flow that could lead to these issues?


How is your token generated? You can check whether your signing key is correctly configured and corresponding and try to configure the corresponding IssuerSigningKey or IssuerSigningKeys in TokenValidationParameters.
And make sure that the program has authentication and authorization enabled
app.UseAuthentication();``app.UseAuthorization();
